# Django ORM relation to a non unique filed

Tags: django, orm

I have a static information of a customer

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

and a DWH style table of the state of his phone with daily data:

```
class Phone(models.Model):
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    day = models.DateField()
    param1 = models.INtegerField()
    param2 = models.INtegerField()
```

my questions is , can I create some kind of "automatic" relation e.g. foreinKey ManytoMany
between customer and the daily phone record using the phone IMEI since the records I collect don't have any knowledge of the Customer and I would like to once connect the customer to all the phone records through the IMEI just once by adding some kind of 3rd table like

```
class CutomerIMEI(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

so I could do phone.customer and customer.phones.filter(day='some day')

Thanks,
Shay

Answer (score 1):

I think you're almost there, except that I would define the `imei` field on `CustomerIMEI` as an actual ForeignKey - you can specify the field to link to in the target table, like this:

```
imei = models.ForeignKey(Phone, to_field='imei')
```

Now, you can use that `CustomerIMEI` as the `through` field of a many-to-many relationship from Customer:

```
phones = models.ManyToManyField(Phone, through=CustomerIMEI)
```

and now your suggested syntax `customer.phones.filter(day='some day')` will just work.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, imei is not unique on Phone since I have a record per day, shouldn't ForeignKey.to_field be unique on the table it belong to?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and i'm getting-  CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
cutomerimei: Field 'imei' under model 'Phone' must have a unique=True constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you looking for [Many-to-Many extra fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)?